# into keyword not available in vb.net (doing left outer joins)

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq, linq-to-xml

I am trying to do left outer join in vb.net linq to xml

```
Dim query = From p In xml1.Elements()
            Join s In xml2.Elements()
                On p.Name Equals s.Name
into sGroup
From s In sGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

[image: squiggly line on my code when executed in vb]

I am wondering why the into keyword is not recognized. I tried it in C# and I was able to make it run. Can anyone point me to the right direction? Is there a counterpart of the into keyword in visual basic?

Comment: Carefully examine answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq

Comment: @T.S. Their recommended way is to use the into keyword. My problem is that the into keyword is not recognized in visual basic linq to xml. I have already run it successfully using C#. But I need it in VB.

Comment: I know, this keyword doesn't work same way in VB. syntax in vb is different. I just don't think you need it.